# Dual boot Linux and FreeBSD through Grub

Tags: linux, boot, freebsd, grub

I am trying to install Slackware Linux and FreeBSD on a single disk. I have installed both the systems. I have also installed grub in MBR through Linux but it has found only Slackware Linux and not FreeBSD. Following is the disk structure as seen by `cfdisk` in Slackware Linux:

[image]

From FreeBSD install disk, the structure is seen as follows:

[image]

I have found following links but they use either gpt or efi, while I have MBR on my disk (I am not sure of difference between these):

[How do you dual boot Debian and FreeBSD using GRUB2?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49293/how-do-you-dual-boot-debian-and-freebsd-using-grub2)

[Unable to dual boot FreeBSD alongside Arch Linux with Grub2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320292/unable-to-dual-boot-freebsd-alongside-arch-linux-with-grub2)

[How to dual boot FreeBSD and Linux on the same Hard disk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/511198/how-to-dual-boot-freebsd-and-linux-on-the-same-hard-disk)

I have tried to add FreeBSD in grub menu through following code:

[image]

However, above gives following error, when grub-mkconfig is run:

[image]

Where is the error and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

A solution using Lilo will also be appreciated (I am not particular about using Grub, although Grub is generally preferred).